# Using Glyphicons keeps overriding homepage CSS

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

How do I use just this? When I evern reference the Script Source the background of the homepage CSS is all removed leaving just a white background. The Envelop icon works fine but for office and dept branding purpose the background is to be kept. How do I incorporate the icon without changing the

above or by

Comment: Can you post your current code?

Comment: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<a href="#Address">above</a> or by <a href="mailto:ProductDesign@example.com"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></a>

Comment: Please use https://jsfiddle.net/ :)